# How can I use SWFLoader purely from Actionscript in Flex 3 and dynamically load content?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, swfloader

I'm doing a Flex 3 project wherein I've to load SWF based on the availability of required file. And the loaded SWF file will be placed in a container (a Panel) at a particular location i.e. coordinates. This I don't want to do in MXML as the SWFLoader container shows a cross marked box if the file is unavailable.

So friends is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new URLRequest object with the url of the file.
- Create a new Loader object.
- Call the Loader object's load() method, passing the URLRequest instance as a parameter.
- Call the addChild() method on a display object container (such as the main timeline of a Flash document) to add the Loader instance to the display list.

Source: [Loading an external SWF file](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_MovieClips_7.html).